# One to One, One to Many, and Many to Many Relationship Performance calculating

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have created a database design for a current project that I am working on. I am new to databases so I read the book "Database Design for Mere Morals" for help and it helped me create my first database design. My question is how will I be able to estimate the performance of all the relationships (One to One, One to Many, and Many to Many)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide the exact database model and the set of queries you intend to run on it.

Comment: The model is pretty big I don't know how to upload the picture onto stack. Could you just give me a basic example of how you would estimate the performance with a model from google or something? Thanks@BrankoDimitrijevic

Comment: Welcome. "Mere Morals"? That's funny enough that I'd be happy to see it left uncorrected!

Comment: Please state database platform plus how you measure performance (interactive response time, reports, etc).

Comment: Well, it is impossible to estimate performance if we don't have that information. It is impossible to even know what the term "performance" means. If you are asking for a general tutorial on database performance,  [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) is an excellent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are in principle no performance problems with any relationships in a relational database . Performance problems come when you query the data. For that reason, you need to know what type of queries are going to be run. Once you know that (and the volumes of data in affected tables), you can create indexes which will help the queries.

When you find a badly performing query, you use what tools you have to analyse the query and show its execution plan. If you're lucky, some tools (SSMS in SQL Server) can give very good hints about what indexes would help but don't exist. if you don't have tools that can do that, you have to study the plan and work out why, for example, it is reading every row in a 10 million row table rather than just the 5 you get at the end. (The latter one would be due to a missing index on the columns you use to restrict the rows returned, either in JOIN clauses or WHERE clauses or both.)

Indexes are what make a DB perform, given a reasonable design in the first place.